# How to modify Python XPATH code using OR operator

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, operators

Below is my code. I want to click the button that says "load all" if it exists. If not, I want to click the "load next". However, with my code below, it's only clicking the "load next" even though a "load all" btn is present. How can I fix this?

```
try:
   load_btn = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div[7]/div/div/div[8]/a[contains(text(),'Load all') or contains(text(),'Load next')]"))) 
   load_btn.click()
   time.sleep(3)                 
except:
   pass
```

I've tried using the `|` operator, but that doesn't give me the answer I need.
How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    load_all_btn = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH," /html/body/div[2]/div[7]/div/div/div[8]/a[2]"))) 
    load_all_btn.click()
    time.sleep(3)                 
except:
    try:
       load_more_btn = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH," /html/body/div[2]/div[7]/div/div/div[8]/a[1]"))) 
       load_more_btn.click()
       time.sleep(3)
    except:
       pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should seperate load button into two distinguish web element instead of one. It is easier to maintain and identify the root cause when think go wrong.

Example code:

```
def click_load_button(self):
    try:
        load_btn = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
        .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(text(),'Load all')]")))
        
        print("Click load all button")
        time.sleep(3)
    except:
        load_btn = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
        .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(text(),'Load next')]")))
        print("Click load next")
        time.sleep(3)

    load_btn.click()
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. This was my original code, but I noticed it fails when there's no comments. I tried using `else: pass` , but that didn't help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
"//a[contains(text(),'Load all')] | //a[contains(text(),'Load next')]"
```

Would be the way to combine them the way if you were looking for two elements and need the first one, or the second if found.

A full xpath is brittle as well.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I tried this, but this didn't help. The scraper defaults to the 'Load next' instead, even if the 'Load all' is there